# jQuery cycle does not work

Tags: jquery, jquery-cycle

I am fairly new to web development and I am trying to use jQuery cycle plugin for a sliding image gallery.

Here is the site in question:

http://rwavproductions.com/front-page-slide/

Before I added the sliding gallery on this website, I made a test page only with the gallery and the code works. The left and right button do work. But I copied the same exact code (including the script tag content) and css, on this new page, and the jQuery does not work as needed.

The images slide implying that the cycle plugin is working, but the next and prev are not working. What could be the reason? could another div be covering the div that the prev and next divs are in, and therefore not registering the click ?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.slideshow').cycle({
        fx: 'scrollHorz',
        prev: '.prev',
        next: '.next',
        timeout: 0,
        rev: true
    });
});
```

Comment: Can we see your HTML? My guess is that you don't have the correct classes set on your elements. Make sure to add `class="prev"` and `class="next"` to your arrows.

Comment: Could you perhaps link to the plugin you are using?

Comment: Please supply the HTML where the plugin is being used.

Comment: Nevermind, see answer below. I think I see what the problem is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah I see. You have a hidden overlay div that is blocking the clicking.

```
<div class="bg_spinner">
```

[image]

Move the div in your markup UNDER `<div class="extra">` and it should work...

Comment: Delete the bg_spinner from your code and everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

for your class named "bg_spinner" add this in the CSS : `pointer-events:none;`

It will probably work.